# Modularity in Android application

Tags: android, design-patterns, modularity

I'm developing Android application in which complexity and features are increasing. Since I'm new I android develop (object programming in general) I need some methods for building modular android application in order to reduce the effort required for any modifiy.

Are there patterns commonly used for this purpose? Can you suggest the most followed guideline, modus operandi, or even books or manual?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is way too open-ended a question for stack overflow-  you can (and do) fill books on it.  I think Pragmatic Programming and Code Complete were very good, but experience will teach you more than any book.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a course at a local community college if available.

Some books:

- "Head First Object-Oriented Analysis & Design" by Brett McLaughlin; Gary Pollice; David West
- "Java™: How to Program, Ninth Edition" by Paul Deitel, et al

As Gabe says this question is too general.